# Disable Safari Extension Non-globally

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, safari, safari-extension

The injection functionality used by Safari extensions can potentially hamper one when debugging (js/css) a page. I've had to manually go into prefs to turn off (disable all) extensions every time I want to debug a complex page...then reverse that pref when/if done.

What recommendations are there for being able to prevent extension loading on a per-tab or per-window basis?

I know when building an extension you can set white/black lists. This isn't practical because I use some extensions that I did not build myself. Plus, a page I may be debugging could be from number of domains (not just localhost, etc.)